# BigQuery partitioned table per integer of size n

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with `userId` column.
`userId` is external id from mysql (auto increment field).
The most common query will be to filter by this id:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE userId=123
```

I want to partition the table by `userId` for better performance and pricing, but google requires me to specify `end` number, but I don't have end, the end is n- Today it's 1000, tomorrow it can be 4000000.

What is the technique to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery has a limit of 4000 partitions per table. Use [clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#ir_partition_cluster) instead. Alternatively you can partition by MOD(userId, 4000).